# How can I change the voice used for the Navigation app on Android?

Tags: motorola-droid, gps, text-to-speech

I love the Navigation app on Android. The voice it uses is fine, but I'd like a little variety. I'd settle for it using the British voice that's available on the phone. However, I've changed the `Text-to-speech` setting on the phone for language to British, but it hasn't changed the voice used by Navigation. There is not a setting in Navigation for the voice. Assuming it uses the "locale" setting, my only options on the Droid are "English" or "Español".

Am I stuck? Does this require root?

In case it matters, I'm still currently on Android 2.2.

Comment: I'm shocked that there isn't a thriving market of user-contributed voice packs...it must be harder to manipulate than I'd thought...

Comment: please let there more that want this!

Comment: It's worth noting that the Navigation voice is (if I understand correctly) not actually generated on the phone; it's downloaded from Google's servers along with the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently not possible with Android 2.2 on Motorola Droid.

Comment: You should suggest it at if it doesn't already exist: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

The SVOX Classic TTS system replaces the (robotic) native Android Pico_TTS
(and Pico_TTS is generating the speech onboard the phone)

free main application
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.svox.classic

$3 voices like the British Victoria voice
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.svox.classic.langpack.eng_gbr_fem