# Is there a way to change the "text to speech" person's voice?

Tags: text-to-speech

By default, it uses the robotic woman's voice for reading text to speech.  Is there a way to change the voice to something else?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/821/how-can-i-change-the-voice-used-for-the-navigation-app-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes install some other TTS engine like, [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.marvin.espeak&feature=search_result) or [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.svox.classic&feature=search_result). And as the market page says,

> To enable it:
>   1. Menu > Settings > Voice input & output > Text-to-speech settings
>   2. Check "eSpeak TTS".
>   3. Set your "Default Engine" to "eSpeak TTS".